# Scaling Text to fit size of Browser with transition

Tags: javascript, css, transform

I have some text that I want to size to 100% of the browser on hovering a button.  How do I make this text fit the browser/container?

I know that with `font size`, you can do something like `font-size:100vw`, however the animation for font-size is jittery, so I can't use this method.

http://jsfiddle.net/0n15mfyL/

For those wondering about the jitterness, it's noticeable when the font is shrinking back down: http://jsfiddle.net/rbk48upd/

Comment: what do you mean by jittery ?

Comment: `.font-box { overflow: hidden }` and slow down the transition a bit...

Comment: @MisterJojo http://jsfiddle.net/rbk48upd/  you can see it when it's scaling down

Comment: There's no delay, it's just jittery, like the font animation doesn't look smooth

Comment: Whar browser/OS are you using? I am not seeing jitteriness on Edge/Windows10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking about [requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

```js
const 
  hoverMe        = document.querySelector('#hover-me')
, animTextSizing = document.querySelector('#anim-text-sizing')
, txtSizeStart   = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(animTextSizing).getPropertyValue('font-size'))
  ;
let sizeLimit = 0,  currentTxtSize = txtSizeStart
  ;
hoverMe.onmouseover =_=>
  {
  sizeLimit = document.body.clientWidth;
  animGrow();
  }
hoverMe.onmouseout =_=>
  {
  sizeLimit = txtSizeStart;
  currentTxtSize++
  animReduce();
  }
function animGrow()
  {
  animTextSizing.style['font-size'] = `${++currentTxtSize}px`;

  if ( animTextSizing.clientWidth < sizeLimit)
    requestAnimationFrame(animGrow);
  }
function animReduce()
  {
  animTextSizing.style['font-size'] = `${--currentTxtSize}px`;

  if ( currentTxtSize > sizeLimit)
    requestAnimationFrame(animReduce);
  }
```

```css
* {
  margin  : 0;
  padding : 0;
}
#anim-text-sizing {
  font-size   : 30px;
  width       : fit-content;
  white-space : nowrap;
  background  : #aabfe5;
  }
#hover-me {
  position   : fixed;
  background : red;
  color      : white;
  top        : 50%;
  left       : 50%;
  padding    : .5rem;
  cursor  : zoom-in;
  }
```

```html
  <div id="hover-me">Hover me</div>
  <div id="anim-text-sizing"> Welcome to this Page </div>
```